# Plotly, why are my bubbles all the same color?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bubble-chart

I have a column called Pizza Shops in my data that has numbers by state, ranging from 10k to over a million (numbers are made up). For some reason every bubble, while it appears to be the right size, all show as the same color (red).

My code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import os

xl_path = "path to XLSX file"

df = pd.read_excel(open(xl_path, 'rb'), sheet_name='Data')
df.head()
scale = 5000
limits = [(0,15000),(15000,50000),(50000,100000),(100000,500000),(500000,2000000)]
colors = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue"]
df['Text'] = df['State'] + '<br>Number of Pizza Shops ' + (df['Pizza Shops']).astype(str)

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(len(limits)):
    lim = limits[i]
    df_sub = df[lim[0]:lim[1]]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        locations=df['State Code'],
        text = df_sub['Text'],
        marker = dict(
            size = df_sub['Pizza Shops']/scale,
            color = colors[i],
            line_color='rgb(40,40,40)',
            line_width=0.5,
            sizemode = 'area'
        ),
        name = '{0} - {1}'.format(lim[0],lim[1])))

fig.update_layout(
        title_text = '2019 US Number of Pizza Shops<br>(Click legend to toggle traces)',
        showlegend = True,
        geo = dict(
            scope = 'usa',
            landcolor = 'rgb(217, 217, 217)',
        )
    )

fig.show()
```

Sample data:

```
| State     | State Code | Pizza Shops |
----------------------------------------
  Texas           TX         13256
  California      CA         500235
  Idaho           ID         4000
  ....           ....        .... and so on
```

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your data? Or at least a sample dataset that resembles the structure of your real world data?

Comment: I'm sure you used the plotly code sample as a reference. I think that sample is color-coded to rank by population in all cities. Don't you want your codes to be color-coded based on store count?

Comment: @r-beginners Correct, I used the plotly reference. And yes I want it color-coded by store count.

Comment: @vestland I edited the post to give a better idea. I have one column "Pizza Shops" with a random number in each row, and another column "State" that has things like "Texas", "California", etc. And "State Code" which would have corresponding abbreviations TX, CA, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with `df_sub = df[lim[0]:lim[1]]` you are subsetting your data frame based on the row indices, and not based on the number of shops. If your data frame has less than 15,000 rows, then all the data points will fall in the first bucket and will be coloured in red.

If you want to subset your data frame based on the number of shops you should replace `df_sub = df[lim[0]:lim[1]]` with  `df_sub = df[(df["Pizza Shops"] >= lim[0]) & (df["Pizza Shops"] < lim[1])]`.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"State": ["Texas", "California", "Idaho", "Alabama", "Arizona", "Georgia", "Washington"],
                   "State Code": ["TX", "CA", "ID", "AL", "AZ", "GA", "WA"],
                   "Pizza Shops": [12500, 25000, 75000, 250000, 1000000, 15000, 100000]})

df["Text"] = df["State"] + "<br>Number of Pizza Shops " + (df["Pizza Shops"]).astype(str)

scale = 2000

limits = [(0,15000),(15000,50000),(50000,100000),(100000,500000),(500000,2000000)]

colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(len(limits)):

    lim = limits[i]

    df_sub = df[(df["Pizza Shops"] >= lim[0]) & (df["Pizza Shops"] < lim[1])]

    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        locationmode="USA-states",
        locations=df_sub["State Code"],
        text=df_sub["Text"],
        marker=dict(
            size=df_sub["Pizza Shops"]/scale,
            color=colors[i],
            line_color="rgb(40,40,40)",
            line_width=0.5,
            sizemode="area"),
        name="{0} - {1}".format(lim[0],lim[1])))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text="2019 US Number of Pizza Shops<br>(Click legend to toggle traces)",
    showlegend=True,
    geo=dict(scope="usa", landcolor="rgb(217, 217, 217)")
)

fig.show()
```